# Notifications are not arriving in the app. (NotificationHubUnauthorizedException: Unauthorized)

Tags: c#, xamarin, push-notification, android-notifications

Notifications are not arriving in the app.

ERROR:

at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallObjectMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x00069] in <0ad2222fd7074badb5de547b1521aab0>:0 
  at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualObjectMethod (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x0002a] in <0ad2222fd7074badb5de547b1521aab0>:0 
  at WindowsAzure.Messaging.NotificationHub.Register (System.String pnsHandle, System.String[] tags) [0x00043] in :0 
  at SiagriAuth.Droid.MyFirebaseIIDService.SendRegistrationToServer (System.String token, System.String pessoaId, System.String conta) [0x00035] in D:\Projetos\SIAGRIAutorize\SiagriAuth\SiagriAuth\SiagriAuth.Droid\Services\MyFirebaseIIDService.cs:74 
  --- End of managed WindowsAzure.Messaging.NotificationHubUnauthorizedException stack trace ---
com.microsoft.windowsazure.messaging.NotificationHubUnauthorizedException: Unauthorized
    at com.microsoft.windowsazure.messaging.Connection.executeRequest(Connection.java:250)
    at com.microsoft.windowsazure.messaging.Connection.executeRequest(Connection.java:172)
    at com.microsoft.windowsazure.messaging.Connection.executeRequest(Connection.java:132)
    at com.microsoft.windowsazure.messaging.NotificationHub.refreshRegistrationInformation(NotificationHub.java:297)
    at com.microsoft.windowsazure.messaging.NotificationHub.registerInternal(NotificationHub.java:391)
    at com.microsoft.windowsazure.messaging.NotificationHub.register(NotificationHub.java:144)

Registration:

```
void SendRegistrationToServer(string token, string pessoaId, string conta)
{
    try
    {
        hub = new NotificationHub(Constants.NotificationHubName, Constants.ListenConnectionString, Context);
        var tags = new List<string>();
        tags.Add($"{pessoaId}-{conta}");
        var reg = hub.Register(token, tags.ToArray()); // Error here
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        App.HandleException(ex);
    }
}
```

In many forums they said it was a date and time zone problem. Corrected the times on both the server and the application, but the notifications still don't arrive, help meee?

**Xamarin.Azure.NotificationHubs.Android version 0.5.0**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually these authorization errors happen when your device's time is different from the time zone used.

Check that the packages are updated to the latest version:

Microsoft Azure Notification Hubs Android
Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base
WindowsAzure.Messaging